# Android service is not working onDestroy

Tags: android, android-service

My Android service is not working when the application gets destroyed in **Xiaomi** devices, but it works perfectly with **Motorola** devices. Currently I have tested my app with **Motorola G 2nd generation**, **Redmi Note 3** and **Mi Pad**.

I want to play music in the background when my app is not in recents.

```
Intent i = new Intent(CollapsingToolbarActivity.this, SongService.class);
startService(i);
```

Comment: *Android service is not working when application gets destroyed* why does that surprise you?

Comment: i want to play music in background when app is not in recents.

Comment: Add text from comment to post; make somewhat readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, i got your point, may be u are missing with permission in security app of xiaomi devices. you must allow your app to autostart. that will prevent your service from destroying.

Answer (score 0):

@K. Gandhi He is not saying the app is destroying when using xiaomi device, he says that `onDestroy();` seems not working on xiaomi device.

@meeta mastani You have to be clear on your question, but as I understand your question, You are using ForegroundService that you want to run your app even when `onDestoy();` is being called or the app is closed.

Answer:
Maybe you are using heavy work on your thread, you have to consider using **asyncTask**, **BackgroundThread**, **BackgroundService** and **ForegroundService.**

- **asyncTask** - for network operations (internet).
- **BackgroundThread** - for heavy work, but when phone sleeps or displays
  turned off, your app will not run or music will not play if you are
  making music app.
- **BackgroundService** - your app is in the background but still active
  (minimize)
- **ForegroundService** - you app is close or destroy but still working or
  playing music.